# Eclipse tooltip preference bar on focus

Tags: 11.10, eclipse, tooltip

When I hover over a suggestion line in Eclipse to view the suggestion tooltip box, and then focus on the tooltip box, a bar gets added to the bottom of the tooltip obscuring some of the text. It's easily fixable by resizing the tooltip box, but it's annoying and ruins my workflow. Any suggestions to get around this?

Sorry if I haven't put this very eloquently, it's hard to explain. Below is a couple of screenshots to give you an idea of what I mean.

[Before I've moved my mouse into the tooltip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6PYr.png)

[After I've moved my mouse into the tooltip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqbjB.png)

(I can't post images because I'm too new.)

I'm on Ubuntu 11.10 using Eclipse 3.7.

Comment: Looks like a bug.  And 3.1.7 isn't available as a package yet.

Answer (score 0):

I can only tell a second workaround: **Reopen the exact same hover**. I don't know why, but the bug occurs only the first time for the same issue (at least for me). When fixing imports, I find that to be the faster solution that resizing the hover box.